# Do I have a guitar with high action?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, action

I am a beginner at guitar. Recently I took my guitar to the store to get its action fixed.But now I see that there is no difference in the actions.

I can fit two 2-mm coins in the 12th fret.I could do this before it was fixed as well.Is this an indication that the action is still high? Should I take it back to the store?

Comment: Is it an acoustic with steel strings, (what gauge?) or a classical with nylon? Whatever, it's too high. Take it back. Sight along the neck - the strings should show that the neck is only very slightly bowed.

Comment: More to the point, is there evidence that the place you took it didn't do anything to it.  How did the action get "fixed"?  Did you ask for lower action or did they fix a twist in the neck, or adjust it so that it tunes properly?  Next time I'd measure everything so you can check when you pick it up.

Comment: While it's easy to just default to "typical" setup guidelines (which would indeed say that 4mm is too high), it's important to remember that variables like action are somewhat personal - what I consider just right may be much too high for someone else. It's also somewhat a factor of the specific instrument - some instruments aren't built in a way that supports a lower action.

Comment: The guy said it had high action and i think he said he adjusted it so it tunes properly.But I dont see any difference.

Answer (score 5):

That's far too high, even for an acoustic guitar (which would typically have a higher action than an electric guitar).

You can look up recommended guitar actions for acoustic guitars online, but off the top of my head I *think* it should be between 2-3mm (depending on the string) on a standard steel string acoustic.

Comment: If you're unsure, take it to a professional to look at for you and be specific about your concerns. If you're confident then this can absolutely be done at home.